# AWS API Gateway Simple Lamda Authorizer failing when used with HTTP API that's using private resource integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, strapi, aws-api-gateway

I have set up API Gateway using HTTP API which is configured to a private application load balancer using a VPC link.

I have a route using this integration and I can request my route **and I get a successful response from my API.**

The problem comes though when I now want to protect this route.
I chose a simple lambda authoriser and set up a basic example I have seen in many tuts being:

```js
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    let response = {
        "isAuthorized": false,
        "context": {
            "AuthInfo": "defaultdeny"
        }
    };
    if (event.headers.authorization === "Bearer secretToken") {
        response = {
            "isAuthorized": true,
            "context": {
                "AuthInfo": "Customer1"
            }
        };
    }
    return response;
};
```

When I attach my authoriser I just get:

```
{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Invalid token."
}
```

this response does not seem to be coming from the authoriser as in cloud watch I can see the authoriser is returning true.

I am not sure if because I am accessing a private resource using an integration with a VPC link if there is something else I need to do, or what I am missing.

I am struggling to find any documentation on authorisers in such a scenario.

Any help most appreciated.

Authoriser settings

[image]

Comment: The private integration should not be the problem, as I have used an authorizer lambda with a private VPC integration before. Can you share how you have configured the authorizer lambda in the HTTP API (since there are different versions of the expected response depending on the configuration).

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the configuration to the question in that case?

Comment: I configured it in the console, choosing type: Lambda,  selecting the lambda function from post, payload format version: 2.0, response mode: simple, Identity sources $request.header.Authorization, Automatically grant API Gateway permission to invoke your Lambda function is switched on.

Comment: Attached screenshot in post

Comment: Is there any other authentication mechanism running on the origin service?

Comment: No, I don't think so, as said if I remove the authoriser I get a 200 response from my API and expected data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238511/discussion-between-matthew-barnden-and-stijndepestel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Api was Strapi CMS, with Strapi if you pass an authorization header to the endpoint even a public one (as I was) then its own authentication kicks in.

So as the header was passed from the lambda authoriser to Strapi, Strapis auth kicked in. Many thanks to @stijndepestel

Comment: For anybody who possibly could come across this issue or one like it. I could not change Strapis behaviour easily, so i just changed the header the token will be sent via. header.auth, you then change this is the lambda and the authoriser.